# How to get WooCommerce order items details in custom email content?

Tags: php, woocommerce, orders, status, email-notifications

The first part of the question is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151498/send-email-notification-on-custom-order-statuses-only-for-woocommerce-sub-orders).

I need to get a list of items from a suborder that have received the status 'shipped' or 'readytocollect' inside $message_body = .

To do this, I was advised to use $order->get_items() in a foreach loop, as described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318).

The problems are:

1. I only manage to receive 1 item from my order. If there are 2 or more items in an order, I still receive 1 item in the letter.
   those. I only get:
   gold ring,
   when to order:
   Gold ring, chain, glasses
2. How can I get each product's image?

Any help is really appreciated.

```
// Enable custom statuses for WooCommerce Orders
add_action('init', 'register_custom_order_statuses');
function register_custom_order_statuses() {
    register_post_status('wc-shipped', array(
        'label' => __( 'Shipped', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
    register_post_status('wc-readytocollect', array(
        'label' => __( 'Ready to collect', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Ready to collect <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Ready to collect <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
}

// Add a custom order status to list of WC Order statuses
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'add_custom_order_statuses');
function add_custom_order_statuses($order_statuses) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status before processing
    foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status) {
        $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;
        if ('wc-processing' === $key) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-shipped']        = __('Shipped', 'woocommerce' );
            $new_order_statuses['wc-readytocollect'] = __('Ready to collect', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}

// Send custom email notifications to sub orders only
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'custom_order_statuses_email_notifications', 10, 4 );
function custom_order_statuses_email_notifications ($order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order) {
    // Targeting sub-orders only
    if ( ! $order->get_parent_id() ) return;

    if ( $to_status === 'shipped' ) {
        $status_label  = __( 'shipped', 'woocommerce' );
        $status_label_soobshenie  = __( 'shipped', 'woocommerce' );
    } 
    elseif ( $to_status === 'readytocollect' ) {
        $status_label  = __( 'readytocollect', 'woocommerce' );
        $status_label_soobshenie  = __( 'readytocollect', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    if ( isset($status_label) ) {
        $mailer        = WC()->mailer(); // load the mailer class.
        $email_subject = sprintf( __( 'readytocollect %s %s' ), $order->get_order_number(), $status_label );

// get an instance of the WC_Order object

foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
    $product_name  = $item['name']; // The product name
    $item_qty      = $item['quantity']; // The quantity
    $line_total     = $item['subtotal']; // or $item['line_subtotal'] 

        $message_body  = '<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <h1>'.$status_label.'</h1>
            <p>'.$status_label_soobshenie.'</p>
            <p></p>
            <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"  style="width: 100%; color: #001a34; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" border="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th width="65%" class="td" style="text-align:left;" scope="col" >'.$product_name.'</th>
                            <th width="10%" class="td" style="text-align:right;" scope="col" >'.$item_qty.'</th>
                            <th width="25%" class="td" style="text-align:right;" scope="col" >'.$line_total.'</th>
                        </tr>
                </table>
        </body>
        </html>'; }
        $message = $mailer->wrap_message( $email_subject, $message_body );
        $mailer->send( $order->get_billing_email(), $email_subject, $message ); // Send email

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will show all suborder items (I have added the product image):

```php
// Send custom email notifications to sub orders only
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'custom_order_statuses_email_notifications', 10, 4 );
function custom_order_statuses_email_notifications ($order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order) {
    // Targeting sub-orders only
    if ( ! $order->get_parent_id() ) return;

    if ( $to_status === 'shipped' ) {
        $status_label  = __( 'shipped', 'woocommerce' );
        $status_label_message  = __( 'shipped', 'woocommerce' );
    } 
    elseif ( $to_status === 'readytocollect' ) {
        $status_label  = __( 'readytocollect', 'woocommerce' );
        $status_label_message  = __( 'readytocollect', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    if ( isset($status_label) ) {
        $mailer        = WC()->mailer(); // load the mailer class.
        $email_subject = sprintf( __( 'Order %s %s' ), $order->get_order_number(), $status_label );

        $message_body = '<html><head></head>
        <body>
            <h1>'.$status_label.'</h1>
            <p>'.$status_label_message.'</p>
            <p></p>
            <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"  style="width: 100%; color: #001a34; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" border="0">
            <thead>';
        
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
            $product = $item->get_product(); // Get product
            $image   = $product->get_image(array( 32, 32 )); // Get product image 32 x 32 px

            $message_body .= '<tr>
                <th width="65%" class="td" style="text-align:left;" scope="col" >'.$image.' '.$item->get_name().'</th>
                <th width="10%" class="td" style="text-align:right;" scope="col" >'.$item->get_quantity().'</th>
                <th width="25%" class="td" style="text-align:right;" scope="col" >'.$item->get_total().'</th>
            </tr>';
        }

        $message_body .= '</thead></table>
        </body></html>';

        $message = $mailer->wrap_message( $email_subject, $message_body );
        $mailer->send( $order->get_billing_email(), $email_subject, $message ); // Send email
    }
}
```

It should work as expected.

Related: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: You have helped me many times already. Thank you, Wizard!

Answer (score -1):

you're overwriting the $message_body  variable inside the foreach loop, which causes it to only contain the last item in the loop.
use

```
$message_body .= '<table>......</table>'
```

to get each product's image, you can use the wp_get_attachment_image_src() that will return the product image URL

here is sample **foreach loop**

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    $product      = $item->get_product();
    $product_name = $product->get_name(); // The product name
    $item_qty     = $item->get_quantity(); // The quantity
    $line_total   = $item->get_total(); // or $item->get_subtotal()

    // Get the product image URL
    $product_image_url = '';
    $product_image_id  = $product->get_image_id();
    if ($product_image_id) {
        $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src($product_image_id, 'full');
        if ($image_data) {
            $product_image_url = $image_data[0];
        }
    }

    // Concatenate item details to the message body
    $message_body .= '
        <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="width: 100%; color: #001a34; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="15%" class="td" style="text-align:left;" scope="col"><img src="' . $product_image_url . '" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="100"></th>
                    <th width="50%" class="td" style="text-align:left;" scope="col">' . $product_name . '</th>
                    <th width="10%" class="td" style="text-align:right;" scope="col">' . $item_qty . '</th>
                    <th width="25%" class="td" style="text-align:right;" scope="col">' . $line_total . '</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>';
}
```